# EF core 3.1+Pomelo Scaffold-DbContext prevent view code generation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

I have recently upgraded from EF core 3.0 to 3.1.1, along with the Pomelo adapter and Tools.
However, after the update the `Scaffold-DbContext` command generates code for all views as well now.

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=SystemDatabase -Provider Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -Force -Context MyDbContext -Project Test.Data
```

I would like the generated DbContext to stay the same like before the update - without views (until throughoutly tested).
How can I disable this new view-generating feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this feature is not implemented in EF Core. However, it is being [tracked on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/21283).

### 1 General solution

The only official way to accomplish what you want, is to use the `-t` command line argument (or `-Tables`, depending on the tool) for every single table you *want* to scaffold (and thereby ignoring all views):

#### 1.1 dotnet ef scaffold

`dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Database=Blogging; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models -t Blog -t Post --context-dir Context -c BlogContext --context-namespace New.Namespace`

#### 1.2 Scaffold-DbContext

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb; Database=Blogging; Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Tables "Blog","Post" -ContextDir Context -Context BlogContext -ContextNamespace New.Namespace`

### 2 Provider specific solution

You can also derive your own custom scaffolder from `MySqlDatabaseModelFactory` and supply all the tables of the database automatically, so you don't have to specify them one-by-one:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Metadata;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure.Internal;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Scaffolding.Internal;

#pragma warning disable EF1001

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class CustomMySqlDesignTimeServices : IDesignTimeServices
    {
        public void ConfigureDesignTimeServices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
            => serviceCollection
                 .AddSingleton<IDatabaseModelFactory, CustomMySqlDatabaseModelFactory>();
    }

    public class CustomMySqlDatabaseModelFactory : MySqlDatabaseModelFactory
    {
        public CustomMySqlDatabaseModelFactory(
            IDiagnosticsLogger<DbLoggerCategory.Scaffolding> logger,
            IMySqlOptions options)
            : base(logger, options)
        {
        }
        
        public override DatabaseModel Create(
            string connectionString,
            DatabaseModelFactoryOptions options)
        {
            //Debugger.Launch();
            
            var tables = new HashSet<string>();
            
            using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                
                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = @"SELECT `TABLE_NAME`
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`TABLES`
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = SCHEMA() AND `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE';";

                    using (var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            tables.Add(dataReader.GetString("TABLE_NAME"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            return base.Create(
                connectionString,
                new DatabaseModelFactoryOptions(tables));
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### 3 Pomelo 3.2.0+ solution using a connection string option

We just added an [issue](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/issues/1120) and a [PR](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql/pull/1121) on our GitHub repository for this feature.

It will be part of the `3.2.0` release and also be available from our [nightly build feed](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql#nightly-builds) in approximately 24 hours.

It introduces a Pomelo and scaffolding specific connection string option `Scaffold:Views=off`, that can be set as part of the command line:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "server=127.0.0.1; uid=root; pwd=; database=So62830251; Scaffold:Views=off" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -c Context
```

Comment: You can also use EF Core Power Tools, which makes it easier or you to make (and preserve) the table selections.